# Redefining ws in a grammar

Tags: grammar, raku

According to the documentation, you can [redefine the `ws`](https://docs.perl6.org/language/grammars#ws) token in a grammar, this token is called automatically in some cases, such as this:

```
grammar Numbers { rule TOP { \d \d } }; 
my $result = Numbers.parse("3 \n 3");
say $result.perl
# OUTPUT: «Match.new(pos => 5, made => Any, from => 0, hash => Map.new(()), orig => "3 \n 3", list => ())␤»
```

One of the advantages of redefining `ws` might be that it will not be thrown away. OK, I'll buy that and use for `ws` the exact same definition that is used internally:

```
grammar Numbers { rule TOP { \d \d }; regex ws { <!ww> \s* } };
my $result = Numbers.parse("3 \n 3");
say $result<ws> # OUTPUT: «Nil␤»
```

Matching works, but $result is still dropped (redefining this to another token that does not use the default ws will work). So is `ws` dropped always?

*Update* This is probably related to [this Rakudo bug](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/issues/1222)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Whitespace not being captured is nothing to do with the definition of `ws`, but rather to do with the way sigspace ("significant whitespace") works.

Sigspace, enabled by the `:s` modifier and on by default in a `rule`, inserts `<.ws>` according to its rules (which can be summarized as "after an atom"). This is a *non-capturing* call to the `ws` rule. Redefining `ws` has no impact on this, since it's a property of the rule calling `ws`, not of `ws` itself.

Indeed, if we write an explicit call to the default `<ws>`:

```
say "1 2" ~~ /\d <ws> \d/
```

The it will capture, the output of the above program being:

```
｢1 2｣
 ws => ｢ ｣
```